# Chrome extension: How to catch redirect?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, http-redirect

I need to catch a http redirect (in order to prevent a redirect loop on a website). I tried using the webRequest API (onBeforeRedirect), but it doesn't seem to catch the redirect.

Here is my manifest.json:

```
{
  "manifest_version": 2,

  "name": "name",
  "description": "description",
  "version": "1.0",

  "permissions": [
    "<all_urls>","webRequest","webRequestBlocking"
  ],
  "background": {
    "scripts": ["test.js"],
    "persistent": true
  }
}
```

And here is my test.js:

```
var callback = function(details) {
    console.log("redirect caught!");
};

chrome.webRequest.onBeforeRedirect.addListener(callback);
```

What am I doing wrong ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You code should be running. However, you can not cancel the redirect. See this official [guide](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/webRequest#event-onBeforeRedirect) . You can check preserve log checkbox in developer console and confirm your log `redirect caught!` is printed.

> onBeforeRedirect Fires when a redirect is about to be executed. A
>   redirection can be triggered by an HTTP response code or by an
>   extension. This event is informational and handled asynchronously. It
>   does not allow you to modify or cancel the request.

Comment: ok, thanks for the answer. So is it not possible to solve my issue ? I'm the user of a site which sometimes presents a redirect loop (A redirects to B, and B redirects to A), and deleting a cookie solves the issue. However, this cookie is needed for authentication, so it can only be deleted when this loop is detected

Comment: @gateQ I understand what your are saying. Try to find another work around.

Comment: Do you have any idea as to what workaround I could use please?

Comment: I can't really say anything until I experience it. But as you said that deleting a cookie solves the issue so you can think of a solution around that cookie.